# For which values ​​of a equation $y=ax^2$ is tangent to $y=\ln(2x)$

Tags: calculus

**For which values ​​of a equation $y=ax^2$ is tangent to $y=\ln(2x)$**

Hello, I tried to solve this question and I can not continue.

$$y=ax^2\\
y=\ln(2x)$$

What I did so far is  to $d/dx$ of $y=ax^2$ $\to$ $2ax=\ln(2x)$, now I dont know if to $d/dx(\ln(2x))$

What you are suggesting? 
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, you are asking for values of $a$ for which the graph of $y=ax^2$ is tangent to the graph of $y=\log(2x)$. So you want values of $a$ for which there is a point $(r,s)$ which is on both graphs (satisfies both equations) and also such that both graphs have the same slope at $x=r$ (so, both functions have the same derivative at $x=r$. This tells you to write down a bunch of equations for $a$, $r$, and $s$, and then try to solve them.

Comment: You are being asked to find any values of $a$ (if they exist) for which the curve for $y = ax^2$ intersects the curve for $y = \ln(2x)$ at _only one_ point.  Where this occurs, the slopes of the two curves at that point will automatically be the same. How might the derivatives of each function be helpful in finding that _single_ point?

Comment: The idea is. If there is a common tangent for both curves then the necessary (but not sufficient) condition is both should have same slope, what you have suggested is right!.But that's not going to do the trick to solve the question.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner. "for which the curve for y=ax2 intersects the curve for y=ln(2x) at only one point". Not always true!. Counter example $y=3x-2$ is a tangent to $y=x^3$ . The straight line meets the curve at points $(1,3)$ (The point of tangency) and also at $(-2,-8)$.link-> https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r5rijpdnra

Comment: Doesn't that make _two_ intersection points?  If we are looking for the location of a _single_ intersection, won't the slopes agree there? (That is the premise of the method of Lagrange multipliers, for example: to locate a point where the local normal lines agree.)  Naturally, we don't expect the slopes to match at every one of multiple intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to throw my hat in here, because there are really only two unknowns and two equations.  The curves are tangent at their one intersection point in the first quadrant.  We want the functions to be equal there:

$$a x^2 = \ln(2x),$$

and their slopes to be equal there as well:

$$2 a x  =  \frac{1}{x}.$$

The derivatives equation gives us $x^2 = \frac{1}{2a}$ .  Inserting that into the functions equation yields

$$ a \cdot (\frac{1}{2a}) = \ln( 2 \cdot (\frac{1}{2a})^{1/2}) \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{2} = \ln 2 - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2a) $$

$$\Rightarrow \ln a = (2 \ln 2) - (\ln 2) - 1  \Rightarrow  a = e^{(\ln 2) - 1 }  =  \frac{2}{e}  \approx 0.7358 .   $$

A graph in fact appears to confirm this.[image] 
The tangent point (x,y) does not have a tidy value; I haven't worked that out yet, as it was not asked for.

EDIT: The defining equation for  $x$  is  $x^2 - \frac{e}{2} \ln x  =  \frac{e}{2} \ln 2$ .  [A little time with Newton's method indicates that the tangent point is approximately $(0.805,0.477)$ .]

ADDENDUM (made a few hours later):  I got curious about a generalization of this.  For $y = ax^n$ tangent to $y = \ln (kx)$  [$n$ and $k$ being positive integers], we find that $a = \frac{k^{n}}{ne}  $, and the location of the tangent point is found from

$$x^n - (\frac{ne}{k^n}) \cdot \ln x = \frac{ne}{k^n} \cdot \ln k  .  $$

Answer (score 2):

We want the tangent line to $y=ax^2$ at some point $(p,q)$ to be the same line as the tangent line to $y=\ln(2x)$ at $(p,q)$.

The tangent line to $y=ax^2$ at a general point $(x,y)$ on the curve has slope $\frac{d}{dx}(ax^2)=2ax$.  Similarly, the tangent line to $y=\ln(2x)$ has slope $\frac{2}{2x}=\frac{1}{x}$.

For the tangent lines to the two curves at $(p,q)$ to be the same,  we need the slopes to be the same, so we need
$$2ap=\frac{1}{p}.\tag{$1$}$$
The point $(p,q)$ must be on both curves, so we also need
$$q=ap^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad q=\ln(2p).\tag{$2$}$$ 
We have three equations in $3$ unknowns $a$, $p$, and $q$, and need to solve for $a$.

From Equation $(1)$ and the first equation of $(2)$, we get $q=\frac{1}{2}$. Then from the second equation in $(2)$ we get $\ln(2p)=\frac{1}{2}$ and therefore $p=\frac{1}{2}e^{p/2}$,

Finally, since from $(1)$ we have $a=\frac{1}{2p^2}$, we can calculate $a$.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 solutions (4 intersecting points):

1. $a \neq 0$  and $Im(W_{-1}(\frac{-a}{2})) \gt -2 \pi$ and $x=\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{-1}{2}W_{-1}(\frac{-a}{2})}$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}a$ $e^{W_{-1}(\frac{-a}{2})}$
2. $a \neq 0$ and $x=\frac{1}{2} e^-{\frac{W(\frac{-a}{2})}{2}}$
3. $a\neq0$ and $Im(W_{-1}(\frac{-a}{2})) \lt 2\pi$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{-1}{2}W_1(\frac{-a}{2})}$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}ae^{-W_1(\frac{-a}{2})}$
4. $a=0$  and $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=0$

where $W_k$ is [Lambert W Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).